# Horizontal Scroll on DropdownButtonFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a form in flutter with a DropdownButtonFormField. When the value of the dropdown menu is too long, it shows an overflow error, how can i make it scroll horizontally the way a normal textfield does?
Here is the code for the DropdownButtonFormField, Thanks in advance.

```
InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelStyle: textStyle,
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 16.0),
                  hintText: 'select expense',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
              isEmpty: _currentSelectedValue == null,
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: _currentSelectedValue,
                  isDense: true,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentSelectedValue = newValue;
                      state.didChange(newValue);
                    });
                  },
                  items: _currencies.map((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the [`isExpanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/isExpanded.html) property of `DropdownButton` to `true`.